# Парсинг цены, регулярка

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Есть такая регулярка - `(\d*) грн|руб|р.|\$\U`

Она должна парсить полную цену с валютой вроде - `500 руб`.Но вместо этого я получу только саму валюту,то есть `руб`.В чем проблема?

Comment: попробуйте заменить пробел на \w и дописать \w в начало регулярки.

Comment: @pavel Ничего не изменилось.

Comment: как именно вызывается эта регулярка?

Comment: Да, число тоже включается в первую альтернативу, то есть _500 грн_ показало бы верно

Comment: `(\d*)\s(грн|руб|р.)` как-то так.

Comment: @pavel да,ваш вариант подходит.Спасибо!:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот другой вариант:

```
/\$\d+(?:\.\d+)?|\d+(?:\.\d+)?\x20+(?:грн|руб|р.|\$)/iu
```

Тест тут: https://regex101.com/r/hD3qA8/1

`\$\d+(?:\.\d+)?` - захват цены в долларах вида: `$100`, `$99.99`

`\d+(?:\.\d+)?\x20+(?:грн|руб|р.|\$)` - захват цен с ведущими цифрами + от 1 до бесконечности пробелов + название валюты.

P.S. Если нужна группа для захвата, то после `/` ставим открывающуюся круглую скобку и перед `/iu` закрывающуюся.

Answer (score 0):

[(\$?[\d.\,]\s*)(\$|руб|грн|р)?](https://regex101.com/r/hD3qA8/1)

Comment: Вы хоть бы ссылку на свой пример теста привели, а не на мой. И посмотрите неадекватное поведение на этом примере: https://regex101.com/r/kB3tC8/1